# Select option in datalist using Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, html-datalist

I have an input together with a datalist like

```
<input type="text" id="theinput" list="thedatalist">
<datalist id="thedatalist">
  <option value="one"></option>
  <option value="two"></option>
  <option value="three"></option>
</datalist>
```

Now, I want to use selenium to select an item in the datalist.

First, I send a key to the input like

```
var remoteWebDriver = (RemoteWebDriver) browser;
var input = remoteWebDriver.FindElementsByCssSelector("#theinput");

input.SendKeys("o");
```

and then I try to treat the datalist as a `<select>` element like

```
var datalist = remoteWebDriver.FindElementsByCssSelector("#thedatalist");
var select = new SelectElement(datalist);
```

I got `UnexpectedTagNameException` with the message

> Element should have been select but was datalist

before I had the chance to `select.SelectByText("one");`.

How do I interact with the datalist with selenium?

Also, it seems like the dropdown closes when the browser loses focus. Is that expected behavior?

Comment: You could just xpath //datalist[id='thedatalist']/option[value()='one'] . Then use .click() on it.

Comment: I will stay away from using values in selectors, I am also not a fan of xpath, but I will try something like your suggestion.

Comment: Personal preference. You could do something like String.Format("/option[value()='{0}']",anyvalue ) in a css selector as well to find based on different value types.String.Format("/option['{0}']",number ) to find index.

Comment: Can you share url here so that I ca give xpath

Comment: Thanks for that, but I will use css @JustinLambert

Answer (score 1):

Select the option element from the datalist using the option child position for example, here I am selecting the second option

```
WebElement lists = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("datalist#thedatalist option:nth-child(2)"))
```

Then you can get the value of the option by using the getAttribute method

```
String optionValue = lists.getAttribute("value"); //two
```

Then you need to input the value into the input field because the datalist provides the values to the input feild:

```
input.sendKeys(optionValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectElement` is a specific class designed to make using SELECT elements easier. There is no such class for DATALIST elements. The source for `SelectElement` is publicly available [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/dotnet/src/support/UI/SelectElement.cs) so you could create a parallel one for DATALIST, if you wanted to.

The simplest solution in this case is to just use

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("theinput")).SendKeys("one");
```

That will select the value you want.

---

If it were me, I would put this in a method so that all I have to do is send the desired option.

```
public void SetOption(string option)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("theinput")).SendKeys(option);
}
```

and then call it like

```
SetOption("one");
```

---

If this is an element you are going to be interacting with a lot and it has a set list of options, you could go one step further and create an enum with values and then have your method take that enum as a parameter. I use this method a lot and it completely eliminates typos, having to look up the list of available options, etc... basically it saves a lot of time.

The enum looks like

```
public enum DatalistOptions
{
    one,
    two,
    three
}
```

The updated method looks like

```
public void SetOption(DatalistOptions option)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("theinput")).SendKeys(option.ToString());
}
```

and the code to call it looks like

```
SetOption(DatalistOptions.one);
```